# Typing emoji in Mac OSX Lion

Tags: macos, emoticons

So 10.7 comes with support for Emoji. I can copy/paste them from the character viewer (like ), but I have no idea how to actually type them.

Answer (score 5):

Go to System Preferences -> Keyboard. Select *Show Keyboard & Character Viewers in menu bar*. From the menu bar now, click *Show Character Viewer*. In the left menu, select Emoji. Either drag or double-click the character you would like.

Comment: fideli is correct. There is no way to type them directly, they're only accessible from the Character Viewer.

Comment: @peelman. Yikes, I did not even see that Nils mentioned the Character Viewer already in the question. This answer seems completely redundant now.

Comment: doesn't make your answer any less relevant.